# android app that accesses the sim toolkit

Tags: android, android-service, sim-toolkit

I want to build an application that accesses information from the sim toolkit. My carrier allows you to access services like checking your account balance, sending and receiving cash and a whole lot of services. Are there any resources, tutorials or even just pointers on how I can access the info in the sim toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

**The SIM toolkit** -

An app which makes calls to lower-level libraries, which in turn interfaces with the modem firmware -

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_stk

Somewhat it depends on  handset's Radio Interface Layer (RIL) implementation.

**NOTE:**

On many devices the RIL is proprietary, so third-party developers only spend time getting the basic stuff like `calls, SMS, data, etc` working rather than spending all their time reverse engineering some crazy closed-source hardware.

WIKI link that can be helpful -

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIM_Toolkit

Comment: Hi..i need get ussd code response and,that response i need to do some modification.its possible bro.. –

Comment: @ved-prakash spent days combing that code .. is there any specific part of it that makes the actual calls to the "lower-level" libs?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access SIM card as secure element and execute STK proactive commands between terminal and SIM, SIM applet must be installed, in order to install SIM applet via OTA or card reader, SIM  Profile(SPI,KIc,KId,TAR,CNTR) parameters and OTA keys are required from SIM card provider.

If this information is obtained, after reading Java Card, SIM Toolkit and Global Platform specifications SIM applet development can be done. Once applet successfully installed on SIM, by sending commands via self defined APDU it is possible to ask terminal to carry out several tasks or register callbacks to catch events when they occur on terminal.